# Tensorflow Random input size

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Acquisition**

I have images that contains defaults areas...Original image's size is arround 3072x16000, that is huge ! Lenght can randomly change, depending on product length.
The image is from a profilometer and look like it :

[image: Image Profilometre]

The speed of the convoyer is fixed. Image length depend on product's.
We can't do "online" processing because acquisition and image processing are from different suppliers.

The first supplier give individual image of products, product lenght is not fixed.

---

**Defaults**

Defaults are quite small (less than 256x256px), then i cropped it, learn a CNN how to recognize it from a conform area (both 256x256x1 px).

***The aim is to focus the network training on ROIs because i don't have a huge database of images.***

I need very high resolution to get small defaults. The classification verdict is on small 256x256px subimage.

I'll have arround 20 classes of defaults and 4 classes of conforms areas (depending on where i am in the image).
I use greylevel image to identify defaults.

I can classify my 256x256px small image between "Good"/"Bad" classes.

[image]

If one area is identified as "Bad", the product is "suspicious" and segregated...

---

**CNN**

I used TensorFlow and retrained a mobilenet network, that work well on 256x256 images, as if training was long.

Now i face other issue. Input images size are in reality arround 3072x16000 pixel.

**Is there a recommanded way to use my pretrain CNN on theses huge images ?**

**How should i cut it and pass it to my CNN?**

Many Thanks !

Comment: Please add details, e.g., is this a classification task on image or pixel level?

Comment: Are you doing binary classification? why are your images so huge? what do the huge images represent?

Comment: I added some more informations.